# Prompting a String value and check if it matches with a specific pattern. How can I solve it by using for loop and substring method?

Tags: java, for-loop

I am doing an assignment which asks me check the given phone number whether it matches the pattern(the pattern is ddd-ddd-dddd) and the numbers are within 0 to 9. I want to use for loop and substring method, but I have no idea how to use them. This code is what I've done so far.

```
public static boolean phoneNum(String s){
  boolean a = false;
  boolean b = false;
  String phone = s.substring(1,4)+s.substring(5,8)+s.substring(9);
  for(int i =0; i<phone.length(); i++){
    y = Character.isDigit(s1.charAt(i));
  }
  if(s.charAt(4)=='-' && s.charAt(8)=='-' && b==true){
    a = true;
    return a;
  }
  return a;
}
```

If I can add for loop, where should it be?

Comment: What's your purpose of using a for loop? And, if you have no idea on what `substring()` is, you can simply refer to the Java API doc.  Please be specific on the problem you are facing.  "Dunno how to do my homework" is not a specific question.

Comment: You _want_ to use `for` loop & `substring`? Or you have to use it?

Comment: @AdrianShum thanks! I just wanted to use for loop to simplify the code, and I was not sure whether I can make a String which is a default pattern of the phone number and then compare it with the prompted String by using for loop

Comment: @lxcky It is not necessary, but I just wanted to use for loop to simplify the code.

Comment: @Shirley I still have no idea what you mean by "simplifying the code by for loop".  In what part you think for-loop will help? Imho, the best way to simplify your code is to make use of regex, so your function can become one line like `return phoneNumber.matches("a regex pattern")`.  I am not giving you the pattern as it should be your work to learn it.

Comment: And, before you learn to "simplify" your code, first learn to write your code in readable way.  Naming variable as `a`,  `b`, `y`, `s` etc make no sense

Comment: @AdrianShum Thank you. I will search more on that, and try to use regex.

Comment: Thanks for the quick accept. I also enhanced my answer a little bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking how to improve the quality of this code, so let's give some ideas:

- change its name to meet java conventions, like *isValidPhoneNumber()*
- you don't need to "carry forward" the results of a previous check. Your method should simply return false immediately whenever it finds a condition to be violated. If all tests pass, you then simply return true in the end.

In other words: what makes your code hard to read and overly complicated are those single character named boolean variables. They mainly add confusion. And keep in mind that your code is ignoring that *y* variable for example. And even if *y* is just a typo that could still be simplified.

And to make that clear: avoid using names like *a* or *b*. These names **mean** nothing. They don't tell the reader anything about the purpose of that variable.